# Convert linq Expression<> to IMongoQuery with c# Driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Given a;

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>> criteria;
```

Is it possible to convert that to an `IMongoQuery`  with the driver?

It looks like it might be amongst the QueryBuilder somewhere, but I can't see it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an example:

```cs
public class C
{
    public int Id;
    public int N;
}

Expression<Func<C, bool>> criteria = x => x.N == 2;
var query = Query<C>.Where(criteria);
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I knew I must have been close, but I'd been trying to use Query<C>.All().

Comment: Is this going to translate to a `$where` query? If so, wouldn't you rather use `AsQueryable` and LINQ translation instead?